# What is th GAN 356 X VIP card for?

Tags: rubiks-cube

I have looked all over the internet but can not find answer to my question. Can someone please help me?!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with the *creation* or *solving* of puzzles.  (It appears to be related more to the *buying* of puzzles.)

Comment: Yes but it is still ABOUT puzzles.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like a sort of warranty card.

[GAN website FAQ](https://www.gancube.com/f-a-q) ("what should I do if my parts is broken") says if you are a "VIP member" you get free parts with free shipping. They ask you to include a picture of your card to certify you are such a member.